# Result Capture in webpage output

Tags: php

I have a PHP file.

Based on the PHP the server generates a output string for example say

```
111 success: id:12345678 |value:10000045
```

Is it possible to store this output in variable and use it? say

```
$input = 12345678
```

I also do not want to store the entire output generated by the server in $input variable ,i just want to save some part of the output in it.

For example i only want to save only id not value.

How can i do these?

Comment: Are you trying to use a separate PHP program to capture the output of another PHP program?

Comment: @imm : I should have mentioned this..i want to use it in the same PHP file..

Comment: How does the server generate the output?

Comment: @CheeseSucker: I do not have any idea and i do not think it should be a concern as i only want to use the result and nothing to do how it generates it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$server_said = file_get_contents('http://serveroutput.com/theoutput.php');
if (preg_match('/id\:(\d*)/', $server_said, $matches)) {
    $input = $matches[1];
}
```

Comment: can you please explain me about what preg_match is doing here...thanxx a lot :)

Comment: The `'/id\:(\d*)/` part is a regular expression. Google it, it's fun! Basically, it pulls the number sequence you need out of the server response.

Comment: you can use "preg_match_all" to catch multiple matches.